# Formating doesn't work when using a formula on a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:

I am using the formula:

```
=IMDIV(F3,0.7)
```

f3 value = 37.44, so the result on the formula cell = 53.9948890...

I need to turn the 53.9948890... into a dollar value, so I want to show it like $53.99

AT THE END I JUST WANT THE DOLLAR VALUE WITHOUT ANY FORMULAS.

How can I format the results of the formula into dollar value?

I tried to highlight the cells and change the formatting but it DIDN'T WORK.

I tried to copy and paste just the numerical values and then formatting the cells, and it DIDN'T WORK.

If I type the number and then I try formatting the cell, then IT WORKS, but then I need to do it manually for hundreds of lines..

Comment: Please don't yell at us =)

Comment: Why are you using IMDIV? I don't see how dollar amounts are related to imaginary numbers. The problem is that IMDIV returns text, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOLLAR` but this returns text again which means you cannot input this into mathematical comparisons/functions as is.

```
=DOLLAR(IMDIV(F3,0.7))
```

---

I would recommend using `ROUND` instead to convert your output to be numeric and then just format the column as currency. Then you have numeric outputs that you can actually feed into functions or compare

```
=ROUND(IMDIV(F3,0.7),2)
```

---

The real question is why are you using `IMDIV` in the first place? As you have discovered, that method will require some downstream work to format to number/currency. Since you are just supplying real numbers, you don't really use the 'special sauce' that is added to the `IMDIV` function. You are just taking extra steps to do a standard division.

i.e. `(37.44 + 0i) / (0.7 + 0i)` = `37.44/0.7` **so why not just use `F3/.7`?**

As you can see in below photo, both outputs return the same number. The only difference is the `IMDIV` function returns this value as string which has to be converted before later use.

[image]

Comment: It's out of scope, but I am curious to know the context behind this question? i.e. dollar amounts having a relationship to imaginary numbers?